# Index/Offset performance is terrible - what am I doing wrong? Python

Tags: python, string, performance

I need to assemble a long text string from xml fields.

XML_FIELD_ONE = "Iamacatthatisoddlyimmunetocatnip"

XML_FILED_TWO = [7,8,24]

FILED_TWO contains the index at which to insert either \n or \r.
If two indexes are 1 apart (like 7, 8), then I need to insert \r\n. If the index is solo (like 24) I need to insert \n.

It takes about 2 minutes to process a 25K line file with this code.
What am I doing wrong?

```
XML_FIELD_ONE = list("Iamacatthatisoddlyimmunetocatnip")
XML_FILED_TWO = [7,8,24]

idx = 0
while idx <= len(XML_FIELD_ONE):
   for position in XML_FIELD_ONE:
       for space in XML_FIELD_TWO:

             if idx == int(space) and idx+1 == int(space)+1:
               XML_FIELD_ONE[idx] = "\r"

                        try:
                            XML_FIELD_ONE[idx+1] = "\n"
                        except:
                            pass

              elif idx == int(space):
                 XML_FIELD_ONE[idx] = "\n"

    idx += 1


new_text = "".join(XML_FIELD_ONE)
return new_text
```

The simple way of doing this is:

```
for offset in XML_FILED_TWO:
    XML_FILED_ONE[offset] = \n
```

But this violates the "if two offsets are together, first one is \r, next one is \n"

Comment: This isn't related, but when will `idx == int(space)` be True and `idx + 1 == int(space) + 1` NOT be True? am I missing something? And what's with the naked `except`? Those are not good. Are you trying to catch an `IndexError`? Usually, you should try to deal with those explicitly, or correct your code so that won't happen... Honestly, I'm having a hard time grokking your code vis a vis your description of what it does... You aren't *inserting*, so to speak, but rather, replacing. And 3 nested loops seems totally unnecessary.

Comment: But, to answer your question, your algorithm here is going to be at *least* quadratic in terms of length of `XML_FIELD_ONE`, and actually, it is O(m*n^2) as far as I can tell, where `n = len(XML_FIELD_ONE)` and `m = len(XML_FIELD_TWO)`... doesn't seem like the right approach at all, given your description of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The space is only 7, 8, 24, meaning it wouldn't be true unless you're at index 7. Meaning index 7 and 8 are replaced by 7, and 8. 

The naked except is to catch the last idx error, yes. When you're at MAX index, you cannot look at MAX index + 1.

Comment: You are confused. `int(space) + 1` will not give you the *next item in the list*. It is *always going to be True* if the left side of the `and` is  True.

Comment: Also, are for example at `7`, are you trying to insert `\r\n` at `7` and then `\n` at `8`? What is the output you are expecting for the example input here?

Comment: Perhaps, but as for idx+1 == int(space)+1, in this example, idx could be any of len(XML_LIST_ONE) values (33) while int(space) can only be 7, 8, or 24.

Comment: I need to insert a space character at every "index" in XML_TWO (7,8,24)
The rule is "If XML_TWO has a pair of numbers right next to one another (7,8) then 7 is \r and 8 is \n. If you have a solo index (24) then its just \n.

I am open to any more sanemethod you know of please :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga

Added a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

The simple way of doing this is:

    for offset in XML_FILED_TWO:
        XML_FILED_ONE[offset] = \n


But this violates the "if two offsets are together, first one is \r, next one is \n"

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but if `idx == int(space)` is True, then `idx + 1 == int(space) + 1` **will always be True**

Comment: The offset numbers in XML_FIELD_TWO are wrong, in that they do not account for the insertion of the newlines. Is this simply because of how you constructed the example, or is this reflective of how the input really appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote a triple loop when you need only one; this is horridly inefficient.  You know exactly where to insert the new items: go directly there, instead of incrementing two counters to find the place.

I'm not sure exactly where you need the insertions, but this should be close.  To keep the original indices correct, you need to insert from the right end and work to the left; that's why I reverse XML_FIELD_TWO.

I left in my debugging print statements.

```
XML_FIELD_ONE = list("Iamacatthatisoddlyimmunetocatnip")
XML_FIELD_TWO = [7,8,24]

print XML_FIELD_ONE
XML_FIELD_TWO = XML_FIELD_TWO[::-1]
print XML_FIELD_TWO
i = 0
while i < len(XML_FIELD_TWO):
    print i, XML_FIELD_TWO[i]
    if XML_FIELD_TWO[i] - XML_FIELD_TWO[i+1] == 1:
        XML_FIELD_ONE.insert(XML_FIELD_TWO[i], '\r\n')
        i += 2
    else:
        XML_FIELD_ONE.insert(XML_FIELD_TWO[i], '\n')
        i += 1

    print "\n", ''.join(XML_FIELD_ONE)
```

Output:

```
['I', 'a', 'm', 'a', 'c', 'a', 't', 't', 'h', 'a', 't', 'i', 's', 'o', 'd', 'd', 'l', 'y', 'i', 'm', 'm', 'u', 'n', 'e', 't', 'o', 'c', 'a', 't', 'n', 'i', 'p']
[24, 8, 7]
0 24

Iamacatthatisoddlyimmune
tocatnip
1 8

Iamacatt
hatisoddlyimmune
tocatnip
```

Comment: Yeah, I used a for-loop and kept track of the number of insertions, but inserting in reverse works great too!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) function to produce a sequence of index/value pairs in a single loop. You can then use the [`list.insert(pos, val)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#typesseq-mutable) method to insert the character you want.

```
XML_FIELD_ONE = list("Iamacatthatisoddlyimmunetocatnip")
XML_FIELD_TWO = [7,8,24]

last_i = len(XML_FIELD_TWO) - 1

for i,p in enumerate(XML_FIELD_TWO):
    ch = '\r' if i < last_i and XML_FIELD_TWO[i+1] == p+1 else '\n'
    XML_FIELD_ONE.insert(p, ch)

print(XML_FIELD_ONE)
```

Comment: Nicely shorter than my "level-appropriate" solution.  I hope others learn from this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a linear algorithm to achieve what you are trying to do. Actually, using `try-except` is perfectly appropriate here, but you should *never have a naked except*:

```
>>> XML_FIELD_ONE = list("Iamacatthatisoddlyimmunetocatnip")
>>> XML_FIELD_TWO = [7,8,24]
>>> insertions = 0
>>> for i, e in enumerate(XML_FIELD_TWO):
...     try:
...         cont = e + 1 == XML_FILED_TWO[i+1]
...     except IndexError:
...         cont = False
...     if cont:
...         XML_FI.insert(e+1+insertions, '\r\n')
...         XML_FIELD_ONE.insert(e+1+insertions, '\r\n')
...     else:
...         XML_FIELD_ONE.insert(e + insertions, '\n')
...     insertions += 1
...
>>> print("".join(XML_FIELD_ONE))
Iamacatt

hatisoddlyimmune
tocatnip
>>>
```

I keep track of the number of insertions which offsets the index used in `.insert` to keep the original indices correct.

Comment: Much thanks for taking the time and helping me think through this!